# Installing FreeGLUT on OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, opengl, glut, freeglut

Now that OS X can use OpenGL 4+ I would like to begin learning more modern OpenGL. The [tutorial](http://openglbook.com/the-book/chapter-1-getting-started/) I am following uses FreeGLUT as the windowing framework. While OS X has Apple's own adaption of GLUT, it is greatly outdated and doesn't work with modern OpenGL. To install FreeGLUT, I first installed X11 2.7.4 (to get GL/glx.h). Then I downloaded the tar ball of FreeGLUT from the FreeGLUT website... version 2.8.1. I then did the following in terminal:

```
./configure  CFLAGS="-I/usr/X11/include/X11/extensions -L/usr/X11/lib" LIBS="-lXrandr -lXxf86vm -lXi" --with-x --x-includes=/usr/X11/include
```

This worked as far as I know. I proceeded to do make all and was given many of these:

```
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-L/usr/X11/lib'
smooth_opengl3.c:131:1: error: unknown type name 'PFNGLGENBUFFERSPROC'
PFNGLGENBUFFERSPROC gl_GenBuffers;
```

I received countless of these errors; the names were all appended with PFNGL.

I then was given a fatal error that stated too many errors were emitted and that the make would be stopped.

Any OS X or OpenGL users out there who know how to fix this?

Comment: Well, that will not work. That tutorial is written for an operating system that uses X11 (presumably Linux or some BSD variant). OS X uses its own window system called Quartz. You also do not load extensions at run-time on OS X. And you use directives like `-framework OpenGL`. There are just too many things wrong with the tutorial you are trying to follow, I would suggest you look at a basic OS X tutorial to get a working build environment and then try to follow along with whatever special thing you are trying to implement.

Comment: Andon M. Coleman - while strictly speaking you are correct that OS X uses Quartz as its native windowing system, the Mac has supported X11 since MacX on System 6.x in the late 1980s.  Today's implementation of X11 for Mac OS X is - more or less - a wrapper around Quartz.  A great many *NIX/X11 programs have been ported to X11.  They don't always build right out of the box, but most of them do.

Answer (score 6):

Lazyfoo's guide to building FreeGLUT (2.8.0) on OSX worked for me, as well - with one modification:  step #4 of their guide (which is for FreeGLUT 2.8.0) advises adding a macro guard to a section of code in a FreeGLUT source file.  That source file in FreeGLUT 2.8.1, however, comes with three macro guards spread over the cited section of code.  Instead of adding Lazyfoo's macro guard, I had to remove the 2nd and 3rd of the macro guards (that come with version 2.8.1) to get the code to compile.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just a point of clarification, the included version of GLUT actually does support modern OpenGL.  Create your context like this:

```
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_3_2_CORE_PROFILE);
```

to get an OpenGL 4.1 context.  I also sequence my includes like this:

```
#include <OpenGL/gl3.h>
#define __gl_h_
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
```

to get access to the newer OpenGL functions and generate compiler errors when using the deprecated OpenGL functions.

To build on the command line just do:

```
clang -framework OpenGL -framework GLUT
```

It works great and there is no need to install any additional libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer but if this still isn't working for you I recommend visiting lazyfoo.net and go to the OpenGL tutorials. The first one will walk you through how to install freeglut (though it might be an older version it worked for me on windows). It has a mac walkthrough as well I just can't tell you how good it is. Worth a try. Also if you are looking for tutorials I have gone through most of them and they are very good.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#if defined(__APPLE__)
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif
```

these are headers for b.c

and this is make file
cc b.c -o b -framework GLUT -framework opengl -Wno-deprecated

./b to view result in gult